# Passing List to a pandas series as index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Can I pass a list to pandas series as index?

I have the following dataframe:

```
d = {'no': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'], 'buyer_code': ['Buy1', 'Buy2', 'Buy3', 'Buy1', 'Buy2', 'Buy2', 'Buy2', 'Buy1', 'Buy3'], 'dollar_amount': ['200.25', '350.00', '120.00', '400.50', '1231.25', '700.00', '350.00', '200.25', '2340.00'], 'date': ['22-01-2010','14-03-2010','17-06-2010','13-04-2011','17-05-2011','28-01-2012','23-07-2012','25-10-2012','25-12-2012']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    buyer_code  date        dollar_amount   no
0   Buy1        22-01-2010  200.25          1
1   Buy2        14-03-2010  350.00          2
2   Buy3        17-06-2010  120.00          3
3   Buy1        13-04-2011  400.50          4
4   Buy2        17-05-2011  1231.25         5
5   Buy2        28-01-2012  700.00          6
6   Buy2        23-07-2012  350.00          7
7   Buy1        25-10-2012  200.25          8
8   Buy3        25-12-2012  2340.00         9
```

**Converting to float for aggregate**

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.4f}'.format
df['dollar_amount'] = df['dollar_amount'].astype(float)
```

**Getting the most important Buyers by frequency and dollars:**

*NOTE: Here I am getting just top 2 buyers, In real example I might have to get upto 40 buyers.*

```
xx = df.groupby('buyer_code').agg({'dollar_amount' : 'mean', 'no' : 'size'})
xx['frqAmnt'] = xx['no'].values * xx['dollar_amount'].values
xx = xx['frqAmnt'].nlargest(2)
xx

buyer_code
Buy2       2,631.2500
Buy3       2,460.0000
Name: frqAmnt, dtype: float64
```

**Grouping buyers and their purchase dates:**

```
zz = df.groupby(['buyer_code'])['date'].value_counts().groupby('buyer_code').head(all)
zz

buyer_code  date      
Buy1        2010-01-22    1
            2011-04-13    1
            2012-10-25    1
Buy2        2010-03-14    1
            2011-05-17    1
            2012-01-28    1
            2012-07-23    1
Buy3        2010-06-17    1
            2012-12-25    1
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

Now  I want to pass my top buyer_codes to my `zz sereis` to get only the transactional data corresponding to those buyers.

How can I do it? I might be on the wrong path here, but kindly help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
a = zz[zz.index.get_level_values(0).isin(xx.index)]
print (a)
buyer_code  date      
Buy2        14-03-2010    1
            17-05-2011    1
            23-07-2012    1
            28-01-2012    1
Buy3        17-06-2010    1
            25-12-2012    1
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

For order need `reindex`:

```
a = zz[zz.index.get_level_values(0).isin(xx.index)].reindex(xx.index, level=0)
```

And for all dates by `buyer_code`:

```
b = a.reset_index(name='a').groupby('buyer_code')['date'].apply(list).reset_index()
print (b)
  buyer_code                                              date
0       Buy2  [14-03-2010, 17-05-2011, 23-07-2012, 28-01-2012]
1       Buy3                          [17-06-2010, 25-12-2012]
```

Comment: How can I get it sorted in order of top buyers?

Comment: Do you think e.g. `Buy3` and then `Buy2`?

Comment: No, Since Buy2 generates more revenue so the output is correct for the sample data. But on actual data its just ordering them in ascending.

Comment: And how can I index through this series? Say I want to get lists for each buyer_code and its corresponding dates?

Comment: Yes, Exactly! :)

Comment: Sorry, but If I want to index through series a, i.e. somehow get a list if indexes of series a, How can I do that? I know that the its a multiIndex series so when I do `a.index` it returns the whole series with buyer_codes as levels. And I can also do `a[Buy2]` to get the corresponding data. But I want to get all the levels in a list and then iterate to get corresponding data. Hope you get me

Comment: Do you think if use `print (a.index)` there is more data as in `print (a)` ? Then need [`remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html) - so `print (a.index.remove_unused_levels())`.

Comment: I can do it this way: `a.index.get_level_values('buyer_code').unique()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162814/discussion-between-el323-and-jezrael).